# Do you use Jest and React Testing Library for automated tests on your react-admin app?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, react-admin

Do you use:

- Jest
- React Testing Library

I'm having a hard time figuring out what to test and how to test it. react-admin has so much based in redux and contexts that it's hard to mock those things so you're focusing on just a single component instead of testing react-admin itself.

Comment: What exactly issue did you face?

Comment: It was really hard to figure out what needed to be mocked. Mainly trying to make sure the component had the right context it needed. Then hopefully being able to mock the data that is injected into the context.